# React arrow function vs bind in Eventhandler. Function component

Tags: javascript

**What's the difference between**

```
onClick={() => setModal({ add: true })}
```

and

```
onClick={setModal.bind(null, { add: true })}
```

If any plus in using bind?

Searched everywhere but couldn't find an answer

I will be glad if you explain in more detail

Comment: The first captures the lexical scope in `this`. The second sets `this` to `null`